# como hacer una query que compare dos datos de una tabla en LinQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hola desarrolladores tengo un problema resulta que estoy realizando un update en linQ y para ello tengo que comparar dos datos para que el update sea correcto (ya que uno de estos datos se repite en mi tabla) pero resulta que linq no me deja comparar con && alguna idea de como hacerlo aca esta el codigo

```
var count = progSemanal.Where(w => w.Codigo_barra.ToString().ToLower() == codmodel.ToString().ToLower()) && progSemanal.Where(t => t.Fecha == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f2)).Count();//Count para update cod barra

 if (count > 0)
 {//Actualiza }else // inserta
```

El error que aparece es este 
No puedo aplicar operando && Iqueriable and int
CodModel es Un codigo entero
y fecha es formato datetime

Comment: Tu problema es que te falta `.Count()` en la primera query y para poder utilizar `&&` con esas 2, necesitas una condición para ambos, o sumarlos y ver en el `if` debajo las condiciones necesarias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que quieres aplicar el operador && despues de cerrar el parentsis del metodo where

enrealidad no se que quieras hacer con tu linea de codigo, pero si lo que quieres es aplicar el ampersand dentro de tu operacion lamba debes de incluirlo dentro de la misma.

```
 var count = progSemanal.Where(w => w.Codigo_barra.ToString().ToLower() == codmodel.ToString().ToLower() && w.Fecha == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f2)).Count();//Count para update cod barra
```

Comment: Es importante en una buena respuesta no solo poner el código, sino también explicar cual era el problema de OP y como tu código lo resuelve.

Comment: gracias por el comentario, añadi la explicacion de donde creo que estaba el error (y me gane la mejor respuesta) +1

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con dos listas diferentes que equivalen a tus tablas siendo dos variables para que puedas comprarlas de esta manera:

```
var primerTabla = Tabla1.ToList();
var segundaTabla = Tabla2.ToList();

var esDiferente =
        primerTabla.Zip(segundaTabla, (j, k) => j.itemNo == k.itemMo).Any(m => !m);
```